# get latest record of multiple groupby laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, group-by

I want to group by an laravel eloquent with two classes come in with() I want to add column of these two with classes in group by

```
$query = CourseEnrolled::with('user', 'course')->latest()->groupBy('course_id','user_id')
```

Here course id come from course table and user id come from user table. it successfully group columns but does sort latest record. It display old record only

I have also tried but still same result

```
$query = CourseEnrolled::with('user', 'course')->orderBy('created_at')->groupBy('course_id','user_id')
```

Comment: Can you please share your model as well. with() only works if you have linked it with other table in database using one-one or one-many methods.

Answer (score 0):

u cant query them directly with the eloquent model of `CourseEnrolled`. if you want to add additional queries with other models, you have to use with() in this way :

```
CourseEnrolled::with('user' , function($user){
            // now u can use any query with user fields
            $user->where('user-name' , 'value');
        })
```

Comment: 'course_id','user_id' are in courseEnrolled

Comment: user_id in CourseEnroll is equal to id in the user's table! btw grouping in SQL is different than grouping arrays or objects of results. if you want to group the results., after oderBy query use `get()` then use the grouping function for collections.

Comment: will you tell me how to groupby latest record in each group

Comment: $query = CourseEnrolled::with('user' , function($query){
                $query->groupBy('id');
            })->with('course' , function($query){
                $query->groupBy('id');
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->groupBy('user_id','course_id');
not working

Answer (score 0):

This query solve my problem

```
    $query = CourseEnrolled::with('user', 'course')->latest()->whereIn('id', function($q){
        $q->select(DB::raw('MAX(id) FROM course_enrolleds GROUP BY user_id,course_id'));
    });
```